# Yarn with Webpack: how to use a TypeScript .ts file that is in an outer Node directory not managed by Yarn/Webpack?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, babeljs, package.json

I'm working on a k6 (https://k6.io/) load testing project that uses Yarn and Webpack.

It lives as a "sub-project" / sub-folder within a larger project/repo. The larger project uses npm Node modules.

I need to grab a secret from AWS's Secrets Manager in my k6 load testing project. There's a TypeScript Secrets Manager client already in the larger/outside project.

I naively tried importing it:

`import SecretsManagerClient from "../../helpers/SecretsManagerClient";`

and using it:

`const value = await SecretsManagerClient.getSecret("fooSecretName");`

And I get all kinds of errors like:

```
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
```

and:

```
SyntaxError: /foo/helpers/SecretsManagerClient.ts: Unexpected token (7:10)

   5 | class SecretsManagerClient {
   6 |
>  7 |   private client;
     |           ^
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Do I need to change settings in `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

My awesome coworker found this resource which may work for us:

https://github.com/grafana/k6-jslib-aws